# SoftLayer_Billing_Item :: getCancellationRequests empty for cancelled hourly virtual server

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use SoftLayer API SoftLayer_Billing_Item :: cancelItem (...) to cancel hourly virtual server billing item,  then calls

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/$billingItemId/getCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[ticket]

to get all cancellation requests.

But this API methods returns empty value even I can find the cancellation ticket was created on customer portal.

Why this API method returns empty value ?  It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks an issue I recomend you to submmit a ticket in softlayer, in order they can look into that.

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a SoftLayer ticket about this.

Answer (score 0):

When a Virtual Guest's billing item is canceled, a "closed ticket" is created immediately, that's why a Cancellation Request is not created. Cancellation Request objects are created for hardware devices such as a Hardware_Server (BMS).

Nevertheless, you could find these generated closed tickets for a Virtual Guest that has been canceled, using the next methods and the next objectMask:

```
SoftLayer_Account::getTicketsClosedToday

SoftLayer_Account::getTicketsClosedInTheLastThreeDays

SoftLayer_Account::getLastFiveClosedTickets

SoftLayer_Account::getClosedTickets

objectMask=mask[attachedVirtualGuests]
```

This mask will retrieve the tickets and the virtual guests related to the canceling operation. Using this information you could for example use the attached virtual guest id and verify the value against the virtual guest id that was intended to be canceled.